# Solve curvilinear integral

Tags: integration, curves

I have difficulty solving the following curvilinear integral

$$\int_{\gamma} x ds$$ where $\rho = 1+ \cos(\theta)$
with $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$

I parametrized the curve with
$$ \begin{cases}
  x= \rho(\theta)\cos(\theta) = (1+\cos(\theta))\cos(\theta) \\
  y= p(\theta)\sin(\theta) = (1+\cos(\theta))\sin(\theta)
\end{cases}$$

As a first step, i calculated the "ds" in this way

$ds = \sqrt{[\rho(\theta)]^2 + [\rho'(\theta)]^2)} d\theta$ where $\rho' = -sin(\theta)$

So $ds = \sqrt{[1+\cos(\theta)]^2 + [-\sin(\theta)]^2)} d\theta = \sqrt{2(1+\cos(\theta))} d\theta =\sqrt{2} \sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)} d\theta$

Then I calculated :
$$\int_{\gamma} x ds = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} [\cos(\theta)(1+\cos(\theta)] \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)} d\theta$$

I don't know if I've done the steps well up to now, but I'm stuck at this integral that I can't approach

Can you give me support please?

---

Thank you for the hint.
$$$$
placing $$1+\cos(\theta) = 2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2}) : $$

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} [\cos(\theta)(1+\cos(\theta)] \sqrt{2} \sqrt{1+\cos(\theta)} d\theta = \sqrt{2} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} (2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})-1)(2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})\sqrt{2\cos^2(\frac{\theta}{2})}d\theta = 2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}4\cos^5(\frac{\theta}{2})-2\cos^3(\frac{\theta}{2})d\theta$$
Now is simple integral.

It's correct?

Comment: What is the definition of the curve $\gamma$?

Comment: @A.P. the curve γ is in polar form ρ=1+cos(θ)  with θ∈[−π,π]

Answer (score 2):

$\textbf{Hint}$:

$$1+\cos\theta = 2\cos^2\frac{\theta}{2}$$

Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Thank you, I supplemented the exercise with the hint.
Is it correct?